# Why is Selenium browser test reverting back to the dev database in my Cucumber scenario?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

My Cucumber scenario is used to test authentication from a third party provider.  What happens is when the facebook connect button is clicked on my registration page a redirect goes to Facebook, and when the credentials are authorized by Facebook, then a redirect happens back to my website.

In my selenium test, it is using the development database on redirect.  I know this because its ending up on a page where there is data which shouldn't be the case because the test database is empty.

features/authentication.feature:

```
  @javascript
  Scenario: Signup through Facebook
    When I am on the signup page
    And I click the Facebook authentication link
    And I fill and submit the Facebook form
    Then I should be on the Add additional information page
```

This fails on the `I should be on the Add additional information page` step because I never get there.  This means a data row exists for the facebook user which means its using the development database. Is there a setting I'm missing?

features/support/env.rb

```
require 'cucumber/rails'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../config/environment')
Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"

# factory_girl Factory definitions
Dir[(Rails.root + "spec/factories/**/*.rb").to_s].each {|factory| require factory}

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
Cucumber::Rails::World.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Capybara.app_host = "http://localhost:3000"`
You're running the server in development environment and making Capybara use it.

Comment: The reason I have the app_host setting is because facebook requires an address.  I've currently given them `http:localhost:3000`.  Is there a way to set a local testing address but at the same time not use the development environment?  Thanks for your help Pedro!

Comment: You need to mock the Facebook requests on your tests.

Comment: Is there a github project out there that has cucumber omniauth-facebook authentication tests?  The guides out there are helpful with the mocking fb requests.

Answer (score 0):

if this is necessity for facebook callback then make sure, your development server is running in test environment

```
   Capybara.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
   Capybara.always_include_port = false
```

using

```
rails s --environment=test
```